# Is there a way to control system music in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, audio-player, background-music

I would like to be able to pause/play and skip music that is playing in a different app (e.g. Spotify/Youtube Music/etc.). Is there a way to control this within a Flutter app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a package for this that I know of. I have an android only app that I am trying to get working, the solution is to make a platform channel and then do something to this effect.

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME = "com.example.myapp/media_control"
  private var methodChannel: MethodChannel? = null
  private var audioManager: AudioManager? = null;

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
      super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

      setupChannels(this, flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  private fun setupChannels(mainActivity: MainActivity, binaryMessenger: BinaryMessenger) {
      methodChannel = MethodChannel(binaryMessenger, METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME)
      methodChannel!!.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if(call.method == "pause") {
                sendMediaButton(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE)
                result.success("Success");
            }
            else if (call.method == "play") {
                sendMediaButton(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY)
                result.success("Success");
            }
            else if (call.method == "skipNext") {
                sendMediaButton(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT)
                result.success("Success");
            }
            else if (call.method == "skipPrevious") {
                sendMediaButton(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS)
                result.success("Success");
            }
      }
  }

    private fun sendMediaButton(keyCode: Int) {
        var keyEvent = KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode)
        audioManager!!.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(keyEvent)

        keyEvent = KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode)
        audioManager!!.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(keyEvent)
    }

}
```